# How to setup NoIP service with multiple NoIP accounts on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-server, domain-name, noip

As suggested in title, is there a way to setup the ubuntu server with multiple NoIP account?

The reason for multiple account is that there are different domains registered in different NoIP account and all these domains needed to point to the same ubuntu server.

It seems that the NoIP client only accept one account in the configuration file. `noip2 -C`

Service provider https://www.noip.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to NoIP services in order to support multiple domains for the same server. You cannot do it with free service.